# What enters in the structure of neutrons and protons in the nucleus of an atom?

Tags: neutrons, protons

**What is the smallest substance in the universe discovered, and it enters in the structure of neutrons and protons in the nucleus of an atom?**

Answer (score 2):

Protons and neutrons consist of three quarks each. These are considered to be fundamental and have no volume so you can't physically get anything smaller than this, as the Standard Model currently stands.

In terms of mass, there are particles that have less mass than quarks, even so far as no mass as is the case for a photon.

[image: stanard model]